# Where to store user sensible data for logged user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bitcoin

I'm designing a web application in MVC/WebApi where the user will have to provide his secret passphase on eachtime he does some action in my app.

To make his life easier, I would like to store this passphase somewhere. I was thinking about a user session or a cookie. How would I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1233104/5325148 This similar thread might be applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information about this subject around here.
in a nutshell, if authentication is what you are after, Microsoft has several frameworks/solutions for this. search for forms authentication(the easiest to apply) , identity, membership, OAuth 2.0, java web token.

Comment: the question is about the security - store sensible info in session or in cookie or somewhere else

Comment: You mean sensitive data? only on the server. the client should not have any sensitive data. only a key for identification from the server. You really should read about Forms Authentication.

Comment: but I dont want to store that information on server side. User will have to put his passphase and it will be send to 3rd party service, but until the user is logged I dont want him to enter his passphase each time

Comment: You do not store anything on the server side, your server creates a token when the user logs in and send it back to the client. Then the conversation between the server and the client will continue based on the this token. When the token becomes invalid, the conversation will end and the user will have to log in again.

Comment: I can not change passphase. Its generated by 3rd party service -  NXT Client. It uses passphases as a private key for the user wallets.

Comment: It's ok if the 3rd party service has a method to validate the token. you need to validate the token with this service every request from the client

Comment: if the pass will be not valid, then I will not able to send a nxt coins. The question is how to store that passphase durring a user session. Imagine a user interface where you can send nxt coins, but to confirm your action you have to type a passphase, and I dont want to force user to type that passphase many times.

Comment: That's the idea behind the token. the user don't even know it's there. you can store the token within a cookie. it's the easiest solution I guess. The cookie comes back and forth automatically from server to client. (btw, I can use some up-votes....)

Answer (score 0):

The cookies and session are working same as asp.net and MVC.

session is stored in the server,cookies are stored in the client browser

session can degrade the performance of server by storing the data

There is more information to know about session and cookie just watch following videos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmziMRE9NQ8][1]

watch the part 60,61,62 these are free videos and you can get more knowledge After watching these videos

Comment: yes, I know; the question is about the security - store sensible info in session or in cookie or somewhere else